# getpixel() doesn't work for png file in c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to convert 28x28 png image to 3d-array(x,y,gray).

[image: the number '3' is 28x28 transparent png image file]

The number '3' in picture is the 28x28 transparent png image file.

my code is below.

```
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);

for (int i = 0; i < 28; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 28; j++)
  {
   Color color = image.GetPixel(i, j);

   if (color.R != 0 || color.G != 0 || color.B != 0)
   writer.Write("[" + i + "," + j + ",1],");  

   else
   writer.Write("[" + i + "," + j + ",0],");
  }
}
```

but the printed text file show only "`[x,y,0]`". 
I think the black pixel will make "`[x,y,1]`" but there are only "`[x,y,0]`".
How can I get the RGB information from pixel?

Comment: If it is an image with transparency then it is crucial that you *also* look at `color.A`.   For example, a named color like Color.Transparency is *black* (R = G = B = 0) with A = 0.

Comment: @HansPassant omg...I got it. Thank you for your help!